# Python selenium unable to scroll and click

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

As i am unable to perform scroll and click on particular website

https://web.sensibull.com/live-options-charts

```
# click on settings
xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/button[3]'
que=browser.find_element(By.XPATH,xpath)
que.click()

# scroll to element
xpath = '/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[10]/div/span[2]'
element = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,xpath)
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);

# click on check box
xpath = '/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[10]/div/span[1]'
que=browser.find_element(By.XPATH,xpath)
que.click()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: click on settings works fine next scroll to element and click on check box does not works

Comment: error as unable to find element

Comment: Remember that Selenium operates in real time.  If it takes a second for the screen to scroll, then you have to wait a second in your code.  Try adding `time.sleep(0.5)` after your clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this line for the scrolling:

```
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

If there is anything else, could you please provide more details?